# How do you calculate the resistor value for a bicolor led

Tags: led, resistors, voltage-divider

R4 and R5 have equal values. For both LEDs the forward voltage is 2V and the forward current is 30mA.

I know how to calculate the correct resistor for a single LED. However in this case I am using a voltage divider to create a 2.5V line so that the bi-color LED can show red or green when LOGIC is 0V or 5V. I am confused as to how to calculate the correct values for the two resisters.

I would appreciate a formula explaining how, and an explanation as to why it is that way.

[Datasheet for the LED](http://www.kingbright-europe.de/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/KPB-2012SURKCGKCVer.2A.pdf)

[image: Bi-color LED schematic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need a source that provides 30mA with 0 or 5V. The voltage at the divider output will be 5V - 2V = 3V ( or 2V if 0V is applied). So we have a 0.5V variation for 30mA. The equivalent source will be 0.5V / 30mA = 16.7 ohms. Each resistor must be 33.3ohms to give parallel combination of 16.7. This will only work if the micro source impedance is low.

Comment: Sorry just edited. Micro output 5V, 2.5V source. Difference is 2.5, current will be 2.5 / r parallel. R parallel = 83.3 ohms. Ear R is 167R

Comment: 4.30am here and having trouble typing, finally got the right text!

Comment: The formula is (V ÷ A) × 2 then? Why is it doubled?

Comment: Take the thevenin equivalent of your divider. It will be 2.5V in series with the parallel combination of the two resistors. We calculated that we want the equivalent circuit to be 2.5V plus 83.3ohms. The parallel combination of 2 equal resistors will be half their value, so each resistor must be twice the required parallel value. A couple of other points, although the LED Max current is 30mA it will most likely perform well at a lower level. Is your micro output capable of 30mA?

Comment: I am having a bad morning here, I forgot to subtract the 2V LED drop this time, answer edit coming up

Comment: I was wondering about of the forward voltage. Yes the output is the signal pin for a battery charging IC so it is more than capable of providing the current. It is specifically meant for bi-color leds.