# Bi-colour LED resistor value

Tags: voltage, led, resistors, voltage-divider, ttl

I am trying to calculate a suitable resistor to give about 2mA to the a bi-colour LED in the following configuration:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn3D2z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED package I am looking at is the L-113SRSGWT (Datasheet [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/d89c/0900766b8139d6f8.pdf)). The Red LED has a typical Vf=1.85V and the green LED has a typical Vf=2.2V.

The idea being that one LED will turn on when a "high" TTL voltage (approx 5V) is applied and the other LED will turn on when a "low" TTL voltage (approx 0V) is applied.

I found a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/213697/how-do-you-calculate-the-resistor-value-for-a-bicolor-led) however I did not quite understand the calculation steps provided. (I have not decided which LED will face which side, I wanted to calculate it first for a rough idea)

The datasheet also does not provide a reverse voltage case for the LED's but I assume that the LEDs will protect one another in the forward and reverse voltage cases. But to be sure, how would I calculate that?

As the two LEDs have different voltage drops this would mean (strictly speaking) I would need two separate resistor values for R1 and R2. But I want to keep them the same for simplicity.

I did a quick calculation for the resistor values with the Red LED Anode facing the TTL logic side and a "high" logic is applied (5v) and got the Thevenin circuit equivalent as:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr8UNk.png)</sup>

As R1=R2, RT=2*R2. Assuming 2mA current, I got RT=V/I= 3.15V/0.002= 1575 Ohms. So R1 and R2 should equal approx 787.5 Ohm. Is this correct, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: If you plan on building this [bi-color LED], I strongly suggest you get one of the LEDs and experiment with resistor values. Reason being, various wavelengths are perceived differently - while current could be exactly 2mA each, one can still seem far brighter than the other.

Answer (score 6):

**Simulate this and you will get 2mA in both the LED.**

replace SW1 with your GPIO directly.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f4ey0Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All resistor value hard to find so use, R1 = 3.7KΩ & R2 = 1.1KΩ

Comment: Thank you for this, it does give 2mA for the green diode but not the red diode. (when the TTL is in the "low" state). I have calculated that for 2mA (approx for an ideal diode, Vsource=5V, VTTL H=5V) there is one intersection that gives R2 as approx 443.93 and R1 as approx 510.75. This seems to be correct using circuitlab.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. Image source: [1 GPIO, bi-colour, 2-pin LED](http://lednique.com/gpio-tricks/1-gpio-bi-colour-2-pin-led/).*

Try converting the parallel resistors into an equivalent voltage source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJRnvq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. When R1 = R2 then the equivalent source voltage is V/2 in series with R/2 (R1 and R2 in parallel).*

If we take *V<sub>f</sub>* = 2 V as an average for the red and green we will then have 0.5 V across R1/2. You want about 2 mA so from * R<sub>1/2</sub> = V/I = 0.5/2m = 0.25k* so 250 Ω. Since the two resistors are equal you'll use 500 Ω.

Try that and see how it looks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I follow the last part (assuming Vf etc..) but I'm not sure I understand the equivalent voltage source part. Could you explain it in a little more detail?

Also, doesn't this calculation only calculate the scenario when the TTL pin is low? Won't the equivalent circuit be different when the TTL pin is high?

Comment: when the current will flow through R1/2 then a voltage drop will across R1 or R2. it won't be 2.5V anymore

Answer (score 1):

An old fashioned TTL high is not +5V, it could be only +2.4V and still be valid.
A TTL low can be +0.4V.